# Use Google DNS service as a secondary/slave to an internal linux BIND9 DNS server

Tags: linux, dns, hosting, server

The company I work for is considering some changes to our DNS. We host an internal linux BIND9 DNS for primary and secondary authoritative DNS. We are thinking of changing either to hosting our public DNS externally, or keeping the primary on-site and move the secondary to a service like Google. I know it doesn't really make sense to keep our public DNS on-site or splitting it up, but the business owners would like to consider all possible options. I have looked through the documentation on-line and have contacted Google directly, but none of the sources I have checked will tell me if Google will allow us to use their DNS service to replicate a primary DNS server housed on-site and act as a secondary DNS for our domains. Does anyone here know if this is possible, and if it is what specifics they require to make it work. Any assistance that can be offered is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Having a name server be a secondary authoritative name server for a domain of yours requires some cooperation from the owner of that server, so the only people who can tell you for sure if Google offers that service are Google themselves.